# python namerror name is not defined

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I am having trouble figuring out why I am getting this error .  My code is this

```
#define the Animal Class

class Animal:
    def __init__ (self, animal_type, age, color):
        self.animal_type = animal_type
        self.age = age
        self.color = color

    def makeNoise():
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        print ("% is % years old and is %" % animal_type,age, color)


#define child classes of Animal 
class Wolves(Animal):
    def __init__(self, animal_type, age, color, wild):

        Animal.__init__(self, animal_type, age, color)
        self.wild = wild
    def __str__(self):
        print ("% is % years old and is % and is %" % (animal_type, age, color, wild))

class Bear(Animal):
    def __init__ (self, animal_type, age, color, sex):
        self.sex = sex
        Animal.__init__(self,animal_type, age, color)

class Moose(Animal):
    def __init__(self, animal_type, age, color, antlers):
        self.antlers = antlers
        Animal.__init__(self, animal_type, age, color)

#add items to each class

wally = Wolves("wolf", 4, "grey","wild")
sally = Wolves("wolf", 3, "white", "tame")

print (str(sally))
print (str(wally))
```

and the full trace-back is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//mgroupnet.com/RedirectedFolders/SBT/Documents/bear51.py", line 41, in <module>
    print (str(sally))
  File "//mgroupnet.com/RedirectedFolders/SBT/Documents/bear51.py", line 24, in __str__
    print ("% is % years old and is % and is %" % (animal_type, age, color, wild))
NameError: name 'animal_type' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you should be calling the instance attributes with `self.animal_type, self.age, self.color`

Comment: When unambiguous, `this` is optional in Java, but `self` in Python is not.

Comment: I fixed the initial problem with your help.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh - well basically you just forgot to use `self.animal_type` in your `__str__` method. Like so:

```
def __str__(self):
    print ("%s is %s years old and is %s" % self.animal_type,self.age, self.color)
```

Just like in `__init__`, to use variables from your instantiated class, you need to use "self", as in "from this animal instance that I'm working on".

Answer (score 0):

In Python methods are just normal functions. Therefore, you cannot access a local variable from one method in another method. The typical way to share information between methods is via `self`. To get `animal_type` in `__str__`, you need use `self.animal_type`. There is no special name space for methods in a class. This means in terms of visibility of names it does not matter if you write functions in a module or methods in a class.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, `self` is not a keyword like `this` in Java. It is just a parameter like any other, which, by convention, is usually called `self`.

When you call a method, like `some_animal.__str__()`<sup>1</sup>, this is actually just syntactic sugar for `Animal.__str__(some_animal)`, where `some_animal` is bound to the `self` parameter.

Thus, in Java (and many other languages) `this` means "look at the current instance for this attribute" and is optional, when unambiguous (i.e. when there is no local variable of the same name), but Python's `self` is not optional. It's just a regular method parameter.

---

<sup>1</sup> `__str__` is not a good example, as you never call it in this way, but rather `str(some_animal)`, but you know what I mean